# Bootstrap carousel and firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, carousel

I recently created a bootstrap carousel to show a series of images. It works perfectly on IE and Chrome. However, it is a bit wonky in Firefox. Since this has to be responsive, I used only one set of images and made different versions.

For my desktop, I have a slider in a thumbnail size / format. When you click on the image, a modal window pops up and the image expands to a bigger size.

For the mobile version, I didn't use the modal window. Each image has the width of a phone and slides.

For the tablet, each slide has three images.

In my mediar query, I would then hide or show different version using "display" based on device resolution.

However, the problem with FireFox was that when the slider makes transition to the next slide, the images expands quickly first, then it goes back to the size that I have set for any particular version.  I don't really want to resize the images based on the version just to keep everything simple.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Lucy

Comment: I just posted my code below. Thanks.

Comment: Lucy, that should be [edit]ed into your post, not posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .imgThumbnail
    {
        height: 100px;
    }
    #imageCarouselNormal
    {
        max-width: 250px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .imgBg
    {
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #636466;
    }

    .mobileImages
    {
        max-width: 250px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #imageCarouselLarge
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 250px;
    }



    #modalWindow
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .fullSize
    {
        width: 300px !important;
    }

    .carousel
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .productImages
    {
        color: Blue;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .carousel-indicators li
    {
        color: Red !important;
        bottom: 5%;
    }

    .arrows
    {
        color: #1A3E6F;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .largeArrows
    {
        color: black;
        margin-top: 150px;
        font-size: 36px;
    }

    .imgCaption
    {
        border: 1px solid white;
        padding: 5px;
        color: black;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "open Sans regular";
        margin: 20px;
    }

    .indicatorBox
    {
        border: 1px solid white;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: Black;
    }

    .borderTest
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .carousel-inner > .item > img .largeImgSlider
    {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        max-width: 200px;
    }

    .transparentBG.modal-content
    {
        background: transparent;
    }

    #myModal .modal-dialog
    {
        width: 500px;
    }

    #modal-bg
    {
    }

    #normalViewSlider
    {
        display: block;
    }

    #mobileView
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .sliderName
    {
        color: #1A3E6F;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: "Open Sans semibold";
        margin-top: -20px;
    }

    .tabletView
    {
        display: none;
    }

    #testClassImg
    {
        background-image: url("http://betarome.mhs.com/Portals/1/DNNGallery/uploads/2015/7/29/Conners3_1.png");
        width: 500px;
        background-repeat: none;
    }
    .carousel-control.left
    {
        background-image: none !important;
    }
    .carousel-control.right
    {
        background-image: none !important;
    }

    .but-pos
    {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -50px;
        right: -50px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 8040;
    }




    @media (max-width: 1024px)
    {

        #normalViewSlider
        {
            display: none;
        }

        #mobileView
        {
            display: none;
        }

        .tabletView
        {
            display: block !important;
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    }

    @media (max-width: 667px)
    {

        #normalViewSlider
        {
            display: none;
        }
        #mobileView
        {
            display: none !important;
        }

        .tabletView
        {
            display: block;
        }

    }




    @media (max-width: 320px)
    {

        #normalViewSlider
        {
            display: none !important;
        }

        #mobileView
        {
            display: block !important;
        }

        .tabletView
        {
            display: none !important;
        }

        #mobileViewSlider
        {
            display: block !important;
        }

    }

    @media (max-width: 480px)
    {

        #normalViewSlider
        {
            display: none;
        }
        #mobileView
        {
            display: block;
        }

        .tabletView
        {
            display: none !important;
        }


    }
</style>
<br />
<!--Start of the Desktop version of the slider-->
<div id="normalViewSlider">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="imageCarouselNormal">
        <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
            <div class="item active row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <img src=""
                            title="Conners 3 Manual Cover" class="img1" onclick="test(event)" id="slider_cover_thumb" /></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <img src=""
                            onclick="test(event)" class="img2" title="Software Iamge" id="slider_softwareImg" /></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <img src=""
                            class="img3" onclick="test(event)" id="slider_CD" title="CD" /></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <img src=""
                            class="img4" onclick="test(event)" title="Conners 3 Sample Report. Visit info.mhs.com/Conners3 to request a full sample report"
                            id="slider_report" /></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <img src=""
                            class="img5" onclick="test(event)" title="Handscored available with MHS QuikScore"
                            id="slider_paperForm" /></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--
    <ol class="carousel-indicators productImages">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#imageCarousel"> </li>
        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#imageCarousel"> </li>
        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#imageCarousel"> </li>
        <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#imageCarousel"> </li>
        <li data-slide-to="4" data-target="#imageCarousel"> </li>

    </ol>-->
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#imageCarouselNormal" class="left carousel-control"><i
            class="fa fa-caret-left arrows"></i></a><a data-slide="next" href="#imageCarouselNormal"
                class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-caret-right arrows"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!--When click on the image, a modal window was triggered-->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content" id="modal-bg" style="border: 1px solid  #1A3E6F;">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #1A3E6F;">
                    <button type="button but-pos" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="color: white !important;"></i>
                    </button>
                    <h4 style="color: White;">
                        Conners 3rd Edition</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="carousel slide text-center" id="imageCarouselLarge">
                        <div class="carousel-inner text-center" id="modalWindow">
                            <div class="item img1 row text-center">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <img src=""
                                        class="largeImgSlider img-responsive slider_cover" /><br />
                                    <div class="imgCaption">
                                        <p>
                                            Conners 3 Manual Cover</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item img2 row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <img src="" />
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="imgCaption">
                                        <p>
                                            Software Image</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item img3 row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center ">
                                    <img src="" />
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="imgCaption">
                                        <p>
                                            Conners 3 Sample Report. Visit info.mhs.com/Conners3 to request a full sample report</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item img4 row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center ">
                                    <img src="" />
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="imgCaption">
                                        <p>
                                            CD</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item img5 row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center ">
                                    <img src="" />
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="imgCaption">
                                        <p>
                                            Handscored available with MHS QuickScore</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--
    <ol class="carousel-indicators productImages">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#imageCarouselLarge"> </li>
        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#imageCarouselLarge"> </li>
        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#imageCarouselLarge"> </li>
        <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#imageCarouselLarge"> </li>
        <li data-slide-to="4" data-target="#imageCarouselLarge"> </li>
    </ol>
    -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <a data-slide="prev" href="#imageCarouselLarge" class="left carousel-control"><i
                            class="fa fa-caret-left largeArrows"></i></a><a data-slide="next" href="#imageCarouselLarge"
                                class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-caret-right largeArrows"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End of the Desktop version of the slider-->
<!--Start of the mobile version of the slider-->
<div id="mobileView">
    <%--<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h4 class="sliderName">Product Images</h4><br /></div>
</div>--%>
    <div id="mobileViewSlider" class="carousel slide mobileImages" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
            <div class="item active row">
                <img src=""
                    class="largeImgSlider img-responsive slider_cover" />
                <%-- <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h4 class="sliderName">Cover</h4><br /></div>
         </div>--%>
            </div>
            <div class="item row">
                <img src="" />
                <%--<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h4 class="sliderName">Software Image</h4><br /></div>
         </div>--%>
            </div>
            <div class="item row">
                <img src="" />
                <%-- <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h4 class="sliderName">Sample Report</h4><br /></div>
         </div>--%>
            </div>
            <div class="item row">
                <img src="" />
                <%--<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h4 class="sliderName">CD</h4><br /></div>
         </div>--%>
            </div>
            <div class="item row">
                <img src="" />
                <%-- <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h4 class="sliderName">Handscored available with MHS QuickScore</h4><br /></div>
         </div>--%>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%-- <div class="indicatorBox">--%>
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="background-color: Black; border: 1px solid white;">
            <li data-target="#mobileViewSlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#mobileViewSlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#mobileViewSlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#mobileViewSlider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#mobileViewSlider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>
        <%-- </div>--%>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#mobileViewSlider" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-caret-left largeArrows">
        </i></a><a data-slide="next" href="#mobileViewSlider" class="right carousel-control">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-right largeArrows"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End of the mobile version of the slider-->
<!--Start of the tablet version of the slider-->
<div class="tabletView">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="tabletSlider">
        <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
            <div class="item active row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src=""
                        title="Conners 3 Manual Cover" class="slider_cover" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src=""
                        title="Software Iamge" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src=""
                        title="CD" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src=""
                        title="Conners 3 Sample Report. Visit info.mhs.com/Conners3 to request a full sample report" /></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <img src=""
                        title="Handscored available with MHS QuikScore" /></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="background-color: Black; border: 1px solid white;">
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#tabletSlider"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#imageCarousel"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#imageCarousel"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="3" data-target="#imageCarousel"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="4" data-target="#imageCarousel"></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <a data-slide="prev" href="#tabletSlider" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-caret-left largeArrows">
    </i></a><a data-slide="next" href="#tabletSlider" class="right carousel-control"><i
        class="fa fa-caret-right largeArrows"></i></a>
</div>
<!--End of the Desktop version of the slider-->
```